# R Change IP Address programmatically

Tags: r, rvest, httr, rcurl

Currently changing user_agent by passing different strings to the `html_session()` method.

Is there also a way to change your IP address on a timer when scraping a website?

Comment: this sounds an awful lot like a method for circumventing terms of use of a website ...

Comment: Take a look here: http://google-scraper.squabbel.com/
This is dedicated to Google scraping but will help for your question as well as by using the information for anything.
It applies to almost any website, most are easier than Google.

Comment: you can use tor and privoxy or direct tor for this purpose. 

Note:- I personally believe there is nothing unethical in circumventing website restriction. Obviously you should not take advantage of the process and make unnecessarily numerous hits to the target webpage.

Comment: Thank you guys. Do you know of a good guide for that @IndranilGayen using R? Failing that could always use Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a proxy (which changes your ip) via `use_proxy` as follows:

```
html_session("you-url", use_proxy("proxy-ip", port))
```

For more details see: `?httr::use_proxy`

To check if it is working you can do the following:

```
require(httr)

content(GET("https://ifconfig.co/json"), "parsed")
content(GET("https://ifconfig.co/json", use_proxy("138.201.63.123", 31288)), "parsed")
```

The first call will return your IP. The second call should return `138.201.63.123` as ip.

This Proxy was taken from http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/ - no garantees for anything...

Comment: Thank you. Are there any restrictions on the IP address or port number that can be used?

Comment: @tonyk What would be such a restriction?

Comment: @tonyk it has to be a valid URL of a proxy server. If you want to use a _socks_-proxy use something like `use_proxy("socks://127.0.0.1", 9050)`

Comment: So for instance it could be any currently valid entry on the https://www.socks-proxy.net/ website?

Comment: Thank you. Sending one request gets me a robot check. Do you know how to view the information sent in the request?

Comment: Habe a Look at ?verbose

Comment: I have tried the sollution and it dose not work for me. `html_session("https://www.maxmodels.pl", use_proxy("95.171.198.206", 8080))` generated the error Error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds`

Comment: Are you sure the proxy is working correctly? Oftentimes proxy's from the web are outdated/blocked by the other site. Did it work using the proxy eg via curl in the Shell?