# R: Switch between VPNs in R

Tags: r, vpn

I am currently accessing the Twitter API in R while relying on several access codes, I crowdsourced from my friends. However, Twitter seems to realise that the requests all come from the same IP, i.e. I can only use one code at a time.

So I was wondering whether there is any way in R to switch between different VPNs within my code? Are there any packages?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting question, too bad it is going to get closed as off-topic (like all library recommendation requests)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41466263/680068

Comment: Maybe related package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iptools/iptools.pdf

Comment: @zx8754: Thank you so much for the links! :) They look very promising

Comment: No problem, feel free to submit your own answer below, if you manage to solve it. :)

Answer (score 1):

in Windows you can use the cmd rasdial like:

```
cmd <- unname(Sys.which("rasdial"))
cmd_args <- c('"VPN NAME"', userID, pass)
system2(command = cmd, args = cmd_args)

# Do your stuff

# Close the connection
cmd_args <- c('"VPN NAME"', '/DISCONNECT')
system2(command = cmd, args = cmd_args)
```